# How do I fix the abline warning, only using first two coefficients?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have been unable to resolve an error when using abline().  I keep getting the warning message: In abline(model): only using the first two of 7 regression coefficients.  I've been searching and seen many instances of others with this error but their examples are for multiple linear functions.  I'm new to R and below is a simple example I'm using to work with.  Thanks for any help!

```
year = c('2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016')
population = c(25244310,25646389,26071655,26473525,26944751,27429639,27862596)
Texas=data.frame(year,population) 

plot(population~year,data=Texas)
model = lm(population~year,data=Texas)
abline(model)
```

Comment: you're using year as a factor. Encode it as a number instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want something like the following where we make sure that `year` is interpreted as a `numeric` variable in your model:

```
plot(population ~ year, data = Texas)
model <- lm(population ~ as.numeric(as.character(year)), data = Texas)
abline(model)
```

[image]

This makes `lm` to estimate an intercept (corresponding to a year 0) and slope (the mean increase in population each year), which is correctly interpreted by `abline` as can also be seen on the plot.

The reason for the warning is that year becomes a factor with 7 levels and so your `lm` call estimate the mean value for the refence year 2010 (the intercept) and 6 contrasts to the other years. Hence you get many coefficients and `abline` only uses the first two incorrectly.

**Edit:** With that said, you probably want change the way `year` is stored to a numeric. Then your code works, and `plot` also makes a proper scatter plot as regression line.

```
Texas$year <- as.numeric(as.character(Texas$year))

plot(population ~ year, data = Texas, pch = 16)
model <- lm(population ~ year, data = Texas)
abline(model)
```

[image]

Note that the `as.character` is needed in general, but it works in `lm` without it by coincidence (because the years are consecutive)