# Plotting adjusted regression with least squares

Tags: r, plot, regression, line, abline

I have a regression model fitted with least squares.

```
library(TSA)
data(hours)
lmhr2 <- lm(hours ~ time(hours)+ I(time(hours)^2), data =hours) 
summary(lmhr2)

plot(hours)
abline(lmhr2)
```

When I run `abline` to the plot, I get this error:

> In abline(lmhr2) : only using the first two of 3 regression
> coefficients

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54737007/how-do-i-fix-the-abline-warning-only-using-first-two-coefficients

Comment: doesnt work, I put it up

Comment: You will need to use the `predict()` function to calculate the dependent variable for a sequence of "hours"

Comment: @Dave2e, please post as an answer?

Comment: Ben, If Nana took the time to accept the answers to the previous questions, I would take more time to provide a formal answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plot your model using `ggplot2::geom_smooth()`:

```
library(TSA)
library(ggplot2)
data(hours)

data.frame(time = time(hours), hours = hours) |>  
  ggplot(aes(time, hours)) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x + I(x^2))
```

[image]